# How to display local image in webview on Android 10

Tags: android, storage

Before Android 10, we can display a local image in WebView as below:

```
// e.g. image local path: /storage/emulated/0/images/image_1.jpg
val html = "<img src=\"file:///storage/emulated/0/images/image_1.jpg\">"
```

But it can't display on Android 10. I tried many ways.

```
val html1 = "<img src=\"file:///storage/emulated/0/images/image_1.jpg\">"
val html2 = "<img src=\"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Aimages%2Fimage_1.jpg\">"
val html2 = "<img src=\"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Aimages/document/primary%3Aimages%2Fimage_1.jpg\">"
```

p.s. And I have got all permissions(read and write via `androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile`) of /storage/emulated/0/images/ via `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

Comment: On Android 10 apps have no access to the path you used. Put the file in getExternalFilesDir() instead.

Comment: `p.s. And I have got all permissions of /storage/emulated/0/images/ via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Impossible. As that action gives you a content scheme.

Comment: I tried to display images saved in my app cache. Even though data stored in app's cache doesn't need storage permission it doesn't work :(

Comment: did you ever solve this?